# How to set the width of a Round Textured Button in an NSToolbar

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

How do you set the width of a Round Textured Button in an NSToolbar, that is, set the width so that it is actually kept at run-time? If I drag a Rounded Textured Button and drop it on an NSToolbar. I've set the width to 25 for both the Custom View/Toolbar Item and the Round Textured Button within it, but as soon as you run the app, the button looks to be three times the width it should be.

I was going to post pictures but I have insufficient reputation points. I hope somebody can figure it out without pictures.

I'm using XCode 6.1.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The anomaly was caused by my use of 64x64 images. Even though it appeared to scale it properly, the stretching of the button must have occurred first before downscaling the image. If I set the button to NSActionTemplate, for example, the button is correctly sized. I'll look for more appropriately-sized images.